# How can I make a video play and pause on a click when using a-frame?

Tags: html, aframe, webvr

I have a month left on my final year project where I am experimenting with virtual reality, in particular with A-frame. I have a set up where there are three videos playing in the file and they are all currently on auto play, however I have been trying to get them to pause and play on a click and have so far been unsuccessful. Here is the snippet of my code that contains the three videos. Any help or guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
<a-entity position="1.5 1.8 0"> 
    <a-video src="#video" width="3" height="2" position="0 0.4 0" begin="click"></a-video>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
</a-entity>

<a-entity position="-3 2 3" rotation="0 90 0"> 
    <a-video src="#video" width="3" height="2" position="0 0.4 0" begin="click"></a-video>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
</a-entity>

<a-entity position="3 2 7" rotation="0 -90 0"> 
    <a-video src="#video" width="3" height="2" position="0 0.4 0" begin="click"></a-video>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
</a-entity>
```

Comment: Check out https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-video-controls. You can either try to use it out of the box, or check out its code. Also in the docs: https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/material.html#video-textures